# PushStreamContent in asp.net core - video start playing only when whole file is buffered

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

i have problem with PushStreamContent in asp.net core.
It display video on the website but my problem is that it will buffer whole file and then play it when my goal is to buffer small part of it and play on the website. Code i have:

My endpoint for playing video in browser

```cs
public IActionResult Play(string file)
{            
    var fileName = "C:\\repo\\trailer1.mp4";
    var video = new VideoStream(fileName);

    var response = new PushStreamContent(video.WriteToStream, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"))
    {

    };

    var objectResult = new ObjectResult(response);
    objectResult.ContentTypes.Add(new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/mp4"));
    return objectResult;
}
```

Ive got VideoStreamClass to help with displaying video

```cs
public class VideoStream
{
    private readonly string _filename;

    public VideoStream(string filename)
    {
        _filename = @"C:\\repo\\trailer1.mp4";
    }
    public async Task WriteToStream(Stream outputStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var buffer = new byte[65536];
            using (var video = File.Open(_filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                var length = (int)video.Length;
                var bytesRead = 1;
                while (length > 0 && bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    bytesRead = video.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(length, buffer.Length));
                    await outputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    await outputStream.FlushAsync();
                    length -= bytesRead;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { return; }
        finally
        {
            outputStream.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my VideoOutputFormatter added to bootstraper

```cs
public class VideoOutputFormatter : IOutputFormatter
{
    public bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        if (context.Object is PushStreamContent)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public async Task WriteAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

        using (var stream = ((PushStreamContent)context.Object))
        {
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            if (context.ContentType != null)
            {
                response.ContentType = context.ContentType.ToString();
            }

            await stream.CopyToAsync(response.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to add atributes to controller "UseBufferedOutputStream" and "UseBufferedInputStream" setted to false but this still dosent work for me

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectResult` is intended for holding an in-memory object as a response. If you want to return an existing file, then `PhysicalFileResult` is probably your best bet.

If you're interested in `PushStreamContent`, I believe the one you're using is for `HttpClient`, not ASP.NET. If you want a `PushStreamContent` equivalent, I have a [`FileCallbackResult` that would work once it's updated for the latest .NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/11/streaming-zip-on-aspnet-core.html).